# P2P communication using Android smartphone and nfcpy

Tags: nfc-p2p

I would like to send a NDEF message from my NFC reader (using nfcpy on Linux) to my smartphone. I have the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright 2010-2011 Stephen Tiedemann <stephen.tiedemann@googlemail.com>
#
# Licensed under the EUPL, Version 1.1 or - as soon they 
# will be approved by the European Commission - subsequent
# versions of the EUPL (the "Licence");
# You may not use this work except in compliance with the
# Licence.
# You may obtain a copy of the Licence at:
#
# http://www.osor.eu/eupl
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in
# writing, software distributed under the Licence is
# distributed on an "AS IS" basis,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
# express or implied.
# See the Licence for the specific language governing
# permissions and limitations under the Licence.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

import logging
log = logging.getLogger('main')

import os
import sys
import time
import argparse

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.split(sys.path[0])[0])
from cli import CommandLineInterface

import nfc
import nfc.snep
import nfc.ndef

class DefaultServer(nfc.snep.SnepServer):
    def __init__(self, llc):
        service_name = 'urn:nfc:sn:snep'
        super(DefaultServer, self).__init__(llc, service_name)

    def put(self, ndef_message):
        log.info("default snep server got put request")
        log.info(ndef_message.pretty())
        return nfc.snep.Success

class ValidationServer(nfc.snep.SnepServer):
    def __init__(self, llc):
        service_name = "urn:nfc:xsn:nfc-forum.org:snep-validation"
        super(ValidationServer, self).__init__(llc, service_name, 10000)
        self.ndef_message_store = dict()

    def put(self, ndef_message):
        log.info("validation snep server got put request")
        key = (ndef_message.type, ndef_message.name)
        log.info("store ndef message under key " + str(key))
        self.ndef_message_store[key] = ndef_message
        return nfc.snep.Success

    def get(self, acceptable_length, ndef_message):
        log.info("validation snep server got get request")
        key = (ndef_message.type, ndef_message.name)
        log.info("client requests ndef message with key " + str(key))
        if key in self.ndef_message_store:
            ndef_message = self.ndef_message_store[key]
            log.info("found matching ndef message")
            log.info(ndef_message.pretty())
            if len(str(ndef_message)) <= acceptable_length:
                return ndef_message
            else: return nfc.snep.ExcessData
        return nfc.snep.NotFound

class TestProgram(CommandLineInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        super(TestProgram, self).__init__(
            parser, groups="llcp dbg clf")

    def on_llcp_startup(self, clf, llc):
        self.default_snep_server = DefaultServer(llc)
        self.validation_snep_server = ValidationServer(llc)
        return llc

    def on_llcp_connect(self, llc):
        self.default_snep_server.start()
        self.validation_snep_server.start()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestProgram().run()
```

Where, and how, should I make a NDEF messege en send it with the existing server to my smartphone? The other way arround (from smartphone to NFC reader is working already).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The Simple NDEF Exchange Protocol that is used to send NDEF messages is a client/server protocol. The code sample provided implements a SNEP server and thus succeeds in receiving an NDEF message from the phone. To send an NDEF message a SNEP client must be used, the equivalent in nfcpy is examples/snep-test-client.py. But the much better option is to use `examples/beam.py send ndef <file.ndef>`.

Comment: Thank you. This will do the work. I thought it was also possible with the server.